# using blastn to search [error]

Tags: blastn

so I'm fairly new to using linux and blast - have encountered an error in my work.

I have created a fasta database with the results in this directory path: 
`~/class/hw/db`

I'm currently trying to run a search against my created database against query sequences in a file called `seqs.fas`.

My code is as follows: 
`blastn -db $db -query seqs.fas -out q1results.txt`

However I keep getting this error: 
`Error: Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: seqs.fas`

`Error:  (CArgException::eSynopsis) Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: seqs.fas`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, and would appreciate any advice to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I remember having this problem in the past, it was encoding related. Rewriting the `-`s manually (the dash sign) should fix the issue, please see [this](http://www.metagenomics.wiki/tools/blast/error-too-many-positional-arguments).

> Problem is a copy & past from the BLAST documentation, all dashes
>   ('–') need to be replaced by hand at the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I've tried multiple ways to get rid of this, including typing out from hand, copying/pasting, and even copying the '-' that shows up when i type ```blastn -help```, however I'm still getting the same error. Just to be clear, dashes ('-') refer to the 'minus' sign next to 0 right? (I'm a Mac user)

Comment: The only think that I can think of is the `$db` variable. Does it somehow contain whitespaces or any other character that the shell would not understand? If the tilde sign (`~`) is part of what `$db` corresponds to (like in your question), you can try changing it to the exact path of your database.

Comment: I've just tried ```blastn -db ~/5030/hw2/db -query seqs.fas -out q1results.txt
```
but that just straight up shows me a ```BLAST Database rror: no alias or index file found for nucleotide database in search path```

Comment: This is another error, I guess you point out to the wrong database path.

Comment: Just to be clear, when i'm doing -db, to which should I refer to: the directory where I have my database, or the entire DB path?